# Hashmap with different color as image

Tags: android, hashmap

i want to have a different color in every list item, to the right of my text.
i m using a hash map and if i wanted to use an image i could do it like this:

```
 map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        map.put("name", getString(R.string.wheretogo));
        map.put("address", R.drawable.sites3);

        mainlist.add(map);
```

How can i do it but not use an image from drawable but #252525 color for example??

thanks (and sorry for my bad english language!)

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you store the Hex code as a string?
They can be changed into actual colors using the android.graphics.Color class.

Answer (score 0):

You can even use:

```
Color.rgb(red, green, blue);
```

Answer (score 0):

Or put the color as int in hex: 0x252525

The alpha channel probably needs to be added. For opaque you need 0xFF252525